# Another MySQl Syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql-error-1064

What is wrong with this?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Service Manager`.`Company` (
  `Company_ID` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `GUID` CHAR(32) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `Region_ID` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `inactive` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Company_ID`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`name` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `GUID` (`GUID` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
>     `Region_ID` INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
>     `name` VARCHAR(45' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably don't want the `UNSIGNED` qualifier on the `CHAR` column.

See [MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 11 Data Types :: 11.1 Data Type Overview :: 11.1.6 String Types :: 11.1.6.1 The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) for more.

Comment: This is correct, UNSIGNED can only be set on integer fields, also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-types.html , where this is mentioned: "All integer types can have an optional (nonstandard) attribute UNSIGNED. Unsigned type can be used to permit only nonnegative numbers in a column or when you need a larger upper numeric range for the column."